# Should we build our SignalR solution into a self hosted app or continue to use it directly within our MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

We've currently got our SignalR 2.x Hub built directly into our MVC Web application. 
It basically works and now are thinking towards performance and scalability.

In terms of performance and scalability, is it better to have our SignalR hub be self 
hosted in it's own app than be buit into the MVC app directly?

What is the best strategy for building out a highly performant/scalable SignalR solution,
especially as we scale out our application across a web farm?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 1):

If you plane to scale signalR you will need to incorporate some sort of back-plane, this is needed if using a load balancer so if one client connects to one of the server all of the other server can send message to that particular client, 
The are server back plane support by SignalR sql,azure and redis
 If performance is an issue i will suggest Redis see [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-redis).
 and also [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance) for more preformace orineted configurations.

That being said SignalR should be hosted in own app behind its own load balancer, that will give more control on it's scalability.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good starting point. I think I need a little more clarification in terms of using a back plane and/or load balancer. I agree that I think the best option is to extract the signalr Hub into it's own self hosted application. I'm not entirely clear regarding the combination of Redis and the load balancer. Is this an either or scenario, or would I use one or the other.  Thoughts?

Comment: Another twist to this is that we have to think of a strategy for guaranteeing message delivery. I envision some sort of scenario where the client sends acknowledgements for each message received. The server side would keep track of messages which weren't acknowledged and have some sort of retry strategy. I need to be aware of this as I come up with the scale out strategy.

Comment: I have updated my answer see above for more info regarding your questions